# How to use nl2br to remove \n and add breaks

Tags: php, html, json, nl2br

I'm having some trouble getting `nl2br` to do what I want.

Can someone explain why `nl2br` doesn't change the `\n` in the JSON data to `< br />` in my PHP?

Here is the code:

```
$page = file_get_contents('JSON_FEED_URL');
$page2 = nl2br($page);
```

When I echo `$page2` and view the HTML page it comes out as a big wall of text.

Comment: It would be useful to see what the data looks like.  
Does the data actually have new lines in it, or does it have the literal characters "\" "n"?

Comment: An example from the feed is "FRIDAY THROUGH WEDNESDAY.\n\nMORE RAIN IS"

Comment: Id seems your `\n`s are just normal chars in the string, and not a "real" line break.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$page = file_get_contents('JSON_FEED_URL');
$page2 = preg_replace("/\\n/m", "<br />", $page);
```

As said, `str_replace` would also work a tad faster, but the above counts of multiline breaks.

Comment: A `str_replace` would do just fine. No need to bring out the big guns.

Comment: But he wants to know specifically about the nl2br method anyway.

Comment: Yes, str_replace works but I just want to understand what nl2br doesnt why it doesn't work in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Because json probably uses \r\n but I though nl2br counted thoses?

Comment: If I echo the $page variable I can see the '\n's and if I echo the $page2 variable after nl2br it's the same with the '\n's still in it.

Answer (score 3):

nl2br does not replace the new lines, only ads the <br> tags. In HTML there is no need to remove the new line characters as they are considered to be white space which is collapsed to a single space for display. This fact is the very reason for having the <br> tag.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that you can see the `\n`s when echoing (instead of a newline in the source), this probably means that your `\n`s are literal, and not "proper" newlines. This is because your JSON is read as a string. Fix this by calling `json_decode();`

```
$page2 = nl2br(json_decode($page));
```

Explanation:
The string

```
line1
line2
```

is in JSON saved as

```
"line1\nline2"
```

but that `\n` is not a real newline, just normal characters. By decoding the JSON, it will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

`nl2br` did not interpret `\n` to `<br />` in HTML because they were literal slashes followed by n.

On your source, the text looks like the following:

```
 FRIDAY THROUGH WEDNESDAY.\n\nMORE RAIN IS
```

Should be something similar to the ff so that it'll be interpreted:

```
 FRIDAY THROUGH WEDNESDAY.

 MORE RAIN IS
```

You can address your problem by using `str_replace()` or if you can update your code when putting content on "JSON_FEED_URL", add `nl2br` before putting those content.

Comment: I don't get why this got downvoted. Care to explain whoever downvoted it?

Comment: Probably because it's "wrong". nl2br will create <br> tags for each `\n`, which the browser should interpret as a newline.

Comment: Whoops, apologies for that. You're right! Will update my answer.